# Artifactory webhook gives "Sending a dummy Webhook failed"

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, webhooks, artifactory

So I have a self hosted Artifactory repository which I wanted to use with a Jenkins pipeline, I deployed Jenkins with ngrok in order to have a fake domain.

When I created the webhook inside Artifactory I used the following URL: **https:///generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=123****

I tried testing it inside Artifactory and keep getting the error alert **"Sending a dummy Webhook failed"** and of course, the pipeline not getting triggered

This is the output inside ngrok command, looks like the webhook is getting triggered but ngrok is showing a 404 error
[image]

I've been stuck for days and I hope someone here can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is in the webhook service configuration, either in Jenkins or in ngork.

Did you try calling the webhook service directly from curl or postman?

Did you try calling the Jenkins webhook service directly to make sure it is configured correctly?

You may try configuring Artifactory to call Jenkins directly by setting urlStrictPolicy to false in system.yaml.
You can read more about configuring Artifactory webhook in the following article:
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-test-webhooks-in-artifactory-and-check-its-request-payload/

Answer (score 0):

You should check in your event-service.log file . Likely DNS resolution failed for the hostname. To debug it, shell within the artifactory host (or container if docker install) and try to curl the endpoint.
Also webhook forbids using local network hostname to prevent from SSRF attempt. if you are sure about what you are doing set event.webhooks. urlStrictPolicy: false in your system yaml